# Using Google Analytics on iOS through AdMob Analytics Addon

Tags: ios, admob, analytics

I have just changed from iAd to AdMob for the ads program on my iOS App.

The thing is that I just hate Apple's statistics at iTunes Connect. I wonder if I can use AdMob's Analytics addon to track all sorts of information such as downloads, devices, etc.

Is there anyway to have an statistical system such as Google Play has?

Answer (score 1):

Well it is little bit hidden... but I have found these two interesting links:

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v2/

https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/conversion-tracking

Good information though.

Comment: Thanks for the links!  First link is legacy, the article has a link to redirect you, however, here is the new link to save you some time: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v3/, the second link is broken.

Answer (score 1):

**iOS 9.3, Xcode 7.3**

Google Analytics has lots of customization options as to what data is gathered.  *"You get out of it as much as you put in."*  I mean, you will need to spend time integrating the analytics correctly to track what you deem significant.  Determining what is "significant" is hard.  The recommended approach is to start small and branch out into more detail later as you acquire customers.

This is what you'd expect as advertised:

> The App Overview report summarizes the most useful information from
>   all of the Mobile App Analytics reports. Individual Mobile App
>   Analytics reports are organized into different categories:
>
> **Real-Time:** See user traffic as it happens on your app. Monitor users, top active screens, top locations, and more. You can use
>   Real-Time as an end to end debugging tool for your Google Analytics
>   SDK implementation.
>
> **Audience:** Get to know the people using your app—where they are, how often and long they use an app, and what devices are popular with
>   your visitors.
>
> **Acquisition:** Find out how often your app is downloaded and installed, and how successful certain marketing campaigns are in
>   attracting visitors.
>
> **Behavior:** Track in detail the ways users interact with your app. Find out which screens are viewed in a typical visit, or set up Event
>   Tracking to analyze custom actions, like button clicks and video
>   plays. Technical exceptions and crashes are also included in this set
>   of reports.
>
> **Conversions:** Know the real value of your app. Set up Goals and Ecommerce to track targeted objectives, like completed sign-ups and
>   product sales.

To anyone who is looking for info on Google Analytics with regard to AdMob, please see this introduction, play the video and tune out for 30 minutes or so, it is very helpful. The topics covered in this link are:

- [About Google Analytics in AdMob](https://support.google.com/admob/answer/3508177?hl=en&ref_topic=3499164)
- [Set up Google Analytics in AdMob](https://support.google.com/admob/answer/3508133?hl=en&ref_topic=3499164)
- [Analyze a new app in AdMob](https://support.google.com/admob/answer/6099562?hl=en&ref_topic=3499164)
- [Create an audience in AdMob](https://support.google.com/admob/answer/6079595?hl=en&ref_topic=3499164)
- [Stop analyzing an app in AdMob](https://support.google.com/admob/answer/6157897?hl=en&ref_topic=3499164)
- [Google Analytics in AdMob FAQ](https://support.google.com/admob/answer/4580332?hl=en&ref_topic=3499164)

Here is the link to how to integrate Google Analytics in an iOS app., [Add Analytics to Your iOS App](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v3/).

Hope this helps!